# Using gesture recognizers to create a scroll view via storyboard

Tags: ios, interface-builder, scrollview, uistoryboard

I want to make a vertical scroll view for my view controller and I really would rather create this via a storyboard and not in code.

How should I go about this?

I see that in the objects library there is a draggable scroll view and draggable tap gesture recognizers. Since I only want vertical scrolling, should I use a swipe gesture recognizer or a pan one?

Should I switch out my general view that I put in the storyboard with the scroll view?

Then make a weak outlet for my scroll view into my code? Can anyone give me a general idea of what I need to do this?

Comment: Go read Apple's Documentation or watch one of the WWDC videos (I remember some great videos from 2011). There's great content out there. Come back to StackOverflow if you have specific questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are requesting cannot be done via interface builder.

It's a common misconception (that to be honest I also initially had) that interface builder ,which the storyboard is part of, is more than an interface layout tool.

It is not like CS5's flash interface builder or iMovie's canvas which allows you to perform visual manipulations.

It's sole purpose is to allow the developer to have a visual of the views and elements they create. It does allow a degree of display related logic to be performed (i.e. positioning of views, definition of outlets attributes & actions methods) but you cannot use it to define any business logic.

You'll still need to write some code for that.

I'd suggest reading [about interface builder here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/InterfaceBuilder/InterfaceBuilder.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009984-CH6)